# Download and use sqlite file in iOS

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, url, download

I have successfully used a .sqlite file when I store it in my project folder. I'm now trying to do the same thing, except pull the file from online instead of storing it locally. Any suggestions based on this code? I'm getting the error message "Problem with prepare statement" from the bottom of the code.

```
    NSData *fetchedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.dropbox.com/s/zpcieluo2qv43vy/builds.sqlite?dl=1"]];
    NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"builds.sqlite"];
    [fetchedData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:filePath];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", filePath);
    }
    if (!(sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK)) {
        NSLog(@"An error has occured.");
    }
    const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM builds";
    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;

    if (sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement");
    }
```

Comment: where does it fail?  one comment is, you are working out the documents directory & file path twice!

Comment: it was printing the error message "Problem with prepare statement" toward the bottom

Comment: and you're also right about getting the filepath twice - I deleted that part of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dropbox URL will not work, you need to use:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zpcieluo2qv43vy/builds.sqlite?dl=1

or you are just downloading a webpage...

Comment: awesome that did it! all I did was change the URL and this all worked